# What do I do now that Ubuntu was installed and it is taking more than 24 hours to reboot?

Tags: boot, system-installation

I downloaded Ubuntu to my laptop and performed the hash check and used Rufus to put the iso image on my flash drive and then I restarted the laptop and booted from the usb. After that was completed a message on the laptop said to reboot, so I did. I had been connected to the Internet by my home wifi and after a few hours I realized that I was not connected to the Internet and I connected via ethernet. Now it has been over 24 hours and my laptop is still trying to reboot after the install. So, what do I do now?

OK, that was easy. Once I powered off the laptop and did a cold boot, Ubuntu loaded. Now all I have to do is learn how to use it. Thanks!

Comment: Try what is explained on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/36717/668959) (with Alt+SysReq ...)

Comment: You need to find out what works and what doesn't. Power off the computer and cold start it. Does Ubuntu boot successfully? If you have a dual boot with Windows, does Windows boot successfully? Edit your question with the results. If one or more OSs can't boot, then [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) may be able to repair the bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you already solved it, so you can mark your own edit as such if you like.
You probably experienced a bug in the installer. In some occasions it does not reboot and thus holding the power button is a solution, as long as there was a message that the installation was finished, it's no problem.

If you find it worth the time, you can file a bug report on launchpad, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu, supplying your system details and the exact conditions to reproduce it.
For that you need the latest BIOS to be installed.

enjoy your fresh Ubuntu installation :)